# How to find position in array after prompting user to select from list using AppleScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, arraylist, applescript

I can't quite figure this one out and I am just getting started with scripting. To explain, I am wanting to use the code below to allow a user to select an item from a list. Then, I want to convert what they selected into the numerical position from the list.

For example, if the user selected iPod, I want it to save their input as 2 instead of iPod.

Here's what I have:

```
set productList to {"iPad", "iPod", "iPhone", "Mac", "Apple TV", "Apple Watch", "Beats", "Apple Watch Edition", "Apple Watch Hermes"}
set yourProduct to choose from list of productList with prompt "Select your product: "

on listPosition(this_item, this_list)
    repeat with i from 1 to the count of this_list
        if item i of this_list is this_item then return i
    end repeat
    return 0
end listPosition

set item_num to my listPosition(yourProduct, productList)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me using the latest version of Sierra.

This will store the "position" in the variable  `property theItemPosition`

```
property productList : {"iPad", "iPod", "iPhone", "Mac", "Apple TV", "Apple Watch", "Beats", "Apple Watch Edition", "Apple Watch Hermes"}
property theItemPosition : missing value

set yourProduct to choose from list of productList with prompt "Select your product: "
set yourProduct to yourProduct as string

findPosition(productList, yourProduct)

set theItemPosition to item 1 of result -- returns the chosen product to its position 

on findPosition(theList, theListProductChosen)
    local theList, theListProductChosen, res
    try
        if theList's class is not list then error "not a list." number -1704
        if {theListProductChosen} is not in theList then return {}
        set res to {}
        script k
            property l : theList
        end script
        repeat with i from 1 to count of k's l
            if k's l's item i is theListProductChosen then set res's end to i
        end repeat
        return res
    on error eMsg number eNum
        error "Can't findPosition: " & eMsg number eNum
    end try
end findPosition
```

Answer (score 1):

While the other answers, at the time of the posting of this answer, do return the chosen items position in the list, they do not account for both choices that can be made with the `choose from list` *command* in the manner in which you've coded it. The only thing you need to do to fix your current *code* as shown, is to:

Change:

```
set yourProduct to choose from list of productList with prompt "Select your product: "
```

To:

```
try
    set yourProduct to item 1 of (choose from list of productList with prompt "Select your product:")
on error
    return
end try
```

What this does, is it handles the user pressing the **Cancel** *button* and or setting the *value* of `yourProduct` to a *string*, not a *list* as what's returned from a `choose from list` *command* if **Cancel** is not pressed. Then your `on listPosition(this_item, this_list)` *handler* will function properly in this particular use case.

Note that there is often more then one way to code something but it usually best to use the KISS principle, especially when one if first learning how to code something.

Answer (score 0):

You are very close.  You just need to add one statement:
`set yourProduct to item 1 of yourProduct`

```
set productList to {"iPad", "iPod", "iPhone", "Mac", "Apple TV", "Apple Watch", "Beats", "Apple Watch Edition", "Apple Watch Hermes"}
set yourProduct to choose from list of productList with prompt "Select your product: "

--- ADD This Line to Get Product from Returned List ---
set yourProduct to item 1 of yourProduct

on listPosition(this_item, this_list)
  repeat with i from 1 to the count of this_list
    if item i of this_list is this_item then return i
  end repeat
  return 0
end listPosition

set item_num to my listPosition(yourProduct, productList)
```

The `choose from list` command returns a list of the selected item(s).  So you must get the item from the list before doing the compare.

For more info, see [choose from list -- AppleScript Language Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_cmds.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH216-SW7)